# Google sheet onEdit when value of a certain cell changes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, syntax

I want cell `J2:K2` to be cleared ONLY when value in `I1` changes.

I have the following script so far :

```
function onEdit(e) {

    if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'i1') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1').getRange('j2:k2').clear() 
    }
}
```

I thought `onEdit` would only fires up when `I1` is changed however range `J2:K2` keeps getting cleared when I try to write values in either `J2` or `K2`.  Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple fix. This works for me:

```
function onEdit(e) { 

  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'I1') {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('sheet1').getRange('j2:k2').clear();
  }
}
```

The problem was your `if` statement condition was not getting met. This is because `.getA1Notation()` returns a [string description of the range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation()) which needs to be exact. Replacing `i1` with `I1` fixes the problem.

Hope this helps!